# When using multiple actions, the animation length property seems to be shared by all actions. How do I fix this?

Tags: animation

I am working with multiple actions for my model's animations.  One of my actions is a basic "standing still" action that just gives the character slight movements while at rest.. this action only needs to be about 10 frames long.  My jump animation is 36 frames.   If I set the "final frame" to 36 for the jump animation, it also gets set for the standing still animation.  How do I fix this so that the animation length is tied to each action?

Comment: Where do you set the "final frame"? In the NLA-Editor you could scale the actions.